# Typeorm - left join and select only relation entity

Tags: typeorm

I have command:

```
                .leftJoinAndSelect("permission.user", "user")
                .where("permission.stream = :stream", {stream: req.params.id})
                .getMany();
```

Which gives me this output:

```
[
  Permission {
    id: 51,
    user: User { nick: 'jmat', password: 'jmat', email: 'jmat@nothing.com' }
  }
]
```

I want only output like this:

```
[
User { nick: 'jmat', password: 'jmat', email: 'jmat@nothing.com' }
  }
]
```

I tried to add rows like this to my code between where and getMany, but it doesnt work. Also tried to use joinAndMap, but didnt solve it neither.

```
.select(['user'])
.select(['permission.user']
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: The first option in my mind:  `.getMany().then(permitions => permitions.map(perm => perm.user)`

Comment: Ok thank you, I was thinking if it can be done in less timple simplicity than O(N), but its probably same time simplicity as some querySelect so I will do it like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the option with `select` and `getRawMany`

```
.leftJoinAndSelect("permission.user", "user")
.where("permission.stream = :stream", {stream: req.params.id})
.select("user")
.getRawMany();
```

Comment: Working, thank you:) If you want same names of atrributes, you should only edit select to this                                                                                                                                           .select(["user.nick AS nick","user.email AS emal"])